# How to give rights to windows user for linux created folder?

Tags: permissions, samba

I am having an issue with some Linux generated folders on a CIFS network share. This folder is created in linux, but I am unable to delete it from the share from a windows machine. Permissions were set with chmod 777 in linux.

How can I give access to the windows users, without having to "take ownership" from the Windows machine, and give full access rights through windows?

Sorry, a bit of a linux noob here.

Comment: good question. really.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I mounted the CIFS share in `/etc/fstab` with `UID=1000` and `GID=1000`. it seems to be working now. To be honest I have no idea. Just did a lot of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses ACLs to represent file permissions. Those are only partly supported in GNU/Linux. Try using the `acl` utility to find out what permissions are assigned to other files on the network share and try to set the same for your files.

THis is kind of an educated guess, since I have never worked with this myself.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been viewed over 3,000 times, so I thought I would give more details on uid and gid when used in fstab, and mounting shares/drives.

When you add UID=,GID= the share that is mounted, will have the permissions of the user of uid, and the group gid applied to the files.  Therefore if in the network share that was mounted, there is a folder with permission 750, the owner will be listed as the user of uid, with full permissions, the group with gid, will be the group owner and have read and execute permissions, and anyone else will have no permissions.

If you have unix mapping setup in Active Directory, or if the share is a windows nfs share, with permissions set, then you should set uid and gid to avoid permission issues.

if you need to find out the uid/gid of a user, you can run:

```
grep <user> /etc/passwd
```

The output will be similar to:

```
www-data:x:33:83:Full Name of user:/var/www:/usr/sbin/nologin
```

www-data being the user, 33 is the uid, 83 is the gid.